# value.GetType().IsSubClassOf(ClassBase) give me the error of "'ClassBase' is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

Tags: c#, reflection

So am trying to check that a property is derived from a base class before storing it in the backing field. However I get the following syntax error `'ClassBase' is a type, which is not valid in the given context` for line `value.IsSubclassOf(ClassBase)` which makes no sense since  ClassBase is a Type and IsSubclassOf is expecting a type.

MCV example below

```
using System;

namespace QuestionIsSubClassOf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var DataStorageClass = new DataStorageClass();

            var DerivedClassA = new ClassDedrivedA();
            DataStorageClass.TypeOfClassBase = DerivedClassA.GetType();

        }
    }

    public class DataStorageClass
    {
        private Type _typeOfClassBase;
        public Type TypeOfClassBase
        {
            get { return _typeOfClassBase; }
            set
            {

                if (value.IsSubclassOf(ClassBase))
                {
                    _typeOfClassBase = value.GetType();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(TypeOfClassBase)} must be a subclass of {nameof(ClassBase)}");
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public class ClassBase
    {

    }

    public class ClassDedrivedA : ClassBase
    {

    }

    public class ClassDedrivedB : ClassBase
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a weird mix of compile-time and run-time type information that you're trying to mix together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `typeof` operator in C#.

```
if (value.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ClassBase)))
{
    _typeOfClassBase = value.GetType();
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(TypeOfClassBase)} must be a subclass of {nameof(ClassBase)}");
}
```

The `typeof` operator returns a `Type` object which corresponds to the type it was passed as an argument. When you're working on an instance you may not necessarily know what that type is so `typeof` cannot be used, which is why the `GetType()` function exists on the `object` class.

**EDIT:**
I'd also like to check if you mean to use `IsSubclassOf` or whether you actually want to use `IsInstanceOfType` / `IsAssignableFrom`.

`IsSubclassOf` does not return true if you're comparing against the same type. Ie

```
typeof(Type1).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Type1)) //returns false
```

If you're always comparing instances against a base type then you can use `IsInstanceOfType`, otherwise you can use `IsSubclassOf` with an additional check for `==`. Alternatively their's `IsAssignableFrom` but their may be caveats with that. I'd always advice reading the documentation - MSDN in this case.

EDIT 2021-03-14:
I know this is an old question, but with newer versions of C# you can use pattern matching syntax which is much nicer.

```
// `is` will match for base and derived types
if(value is ClassBase)
    _typeOfClassBase = value.GetType();
else
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);
```

Comment: For my purpose in my Real Life code, the equivalent to ClassBase is abstract so it can't be instanced but, that is good to know.